# What is this program called and where can I learn about it?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, software

I've seen a video of someone who created an intelligent waste bin. It could catch objects you threw at it by observing thrown objects with Kinect and driving at the location of impact ([YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cauJEEaqSFc)).

He used a program to design the circuits to control the bin, but I couldn't find out what it is. I hope someone here knows it. Here are some screenshots from the video (sorry about the quality, the video is 360p):

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

These might be from an other application, I'm not sure:

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks to be Eagle, a popular schematic and layout package. http://www.cadsoftusa.com/

Comment: @downvoter Why do you downvote me?

Comment: Don't worry about the downvote.

Comment: Looks like Kicad: https://www.kicad.org [Edited by a moderator.]

Comment: @jippie maybe the board layout, but the schematic layout is almost certainly Eagle.

Answer (score 1):

The software is [EAGLE PCB Designer](http://www.cadsoftusa.com/).